# Difference between text-height and text-depth in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is from the manual (version 2.10, page 183):

> This option works like text height, only for the depth of the text
>   box. This option is mostly useful when you need to ensure a uniform
>   depth of text boxes that need to be aligned.

It's not clear where the difference is.

Comment: Does this question/answer help: [Confused with TeX terminology: height, depth, width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40977/confused-with-tex-terminology-height-depth-width)

Comment: For completeness, please specify the version of the manual and the page on which that quote can be found.