# Use dimensions \totalheight \depth for inline TikZ drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths, dimensions

I want to use the current text's dimensional properties for constructing an inline TikZ image, such as an icon.
The properties I have in mind for use are

```
\height
\depth
\totalheight
```

as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40977/31877).

What I want to achieve is something like the following, but instead of using `ex` units,  want to be sure the drawing fits into the line *exactly*.
[image: bad rendering]

```
\tikz[baseline={1ex}] \draw[draw=black, fill=blue, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (5ex,3ex) ;
Signal
```

Please observe that this code lets the drawing start too low (below the "g" in "Signal") and end too high (above the "S" in Signal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `node` and control its dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{
\tikz[baseline=(a.base)] \node[draw=black, fill=blue, rectangle, rounded corners,inner sep=0, outer sep=0,minimum width=5ex] (a) {\vphantom{Sg}} ;
Signal}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `\vphantom` adds the total height (i.e., height of `S` and depth of `g`)

PS `\fbox` is there just to show the heights.

Comment: Nice solution. Is there another way to create the `\vphantom`? One that does not rely on the looks of the current font (particularly the S and g letters) for spanning all the way from top to bottom?

Comment: @derabbink `calc` also provides `\heightof` and `\depthof` macros, but they again rely on the font.