# Standalone: document size

Tags: margins, standalone

For me the "standalone" documents is useful to produce a document with a size that matches exactly the document. However, here is an example where the final size is to small:

[image]

Here is the same document, with an aditional 'A':

[image]

Do you know why the size of the first arrow is not the good one, and how to correct that?

Thank you!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}$\leftarrow$\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the TeX Book says (p. 63)

> From TeX's viewpoint, a single character from a font is a box [...]
> The character shape need not fit inside the boundaries of its box.

Here we have such a situation: the `\leftarrow` is larger than the box, as the following snippet shows

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\mathsurround0pt % for safety
\fboxsep-.1pt
\fboxrule.1pt
\fbox{$\leftarrow$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, `standalone` doesn't know that, so we must force it to consider a somewhat larger box. One easy way is to insert some vertical phantom, like `\vphantom{A}` or even a simple `\strut`. Alternatively, the `standalone` class accepts an optional argument `border` with syntax

```
border=〈length (all sides)〉
border={〈length (left/right)〉 〈length (bottom/top)〉}
border={〈length (left)〉 〈length (right)〉 〈length (bottom)〉 〈length (top)〉}
```

So in this case one might use

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
```

or

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 0pt 0pt 2pt}]{standalone}
```

if you want the border only above.

Comment: Does this helps? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149500/use-dimensions-totalheight-depth-for-inline-tikz-drawing ...  may be a `\vphantom` will do the work... or `totalheightof` from `calc` package...

Comment: @koleygr Of course `\vphantom` would work too; `\strut` is even simpler. But sometimes you have glyphs that protrude _horizontally_ out of the box, so an overall border is in my opinion the easiest way to cover all cases.

Comment: You can also specify a separate border for each side, e.g. `border={0pt 0pt 0pt 2pt}` (left right bottom top) to only add those 2pt at the top.

Comment: Is the ordering for border: left bottom right top?

Comment: @Teepeemm No: left/right/bottom/top. It's written in the answer and in Torbjørn's comment.