# Why do \sqrt{1} and \sqrt{-1} have different heights?

Tags: math-mode, height, sqrt

I noticed that the heights of `\sqrt{1}` and `\sqrt{-1}` are different. For instance, when they are in between `\left(` and `\right)` parentheses, I must write a character of zero-width (e.g. `\sqrt{-1\mathstrut}`).

[image: sqrt sizes]

Why do `\sqrt{1}` and `\sqrt{-1}` behave so different?

---

This is an example with a slightly more complicated expression:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
$$ \left( 10 + \sqrt{7}\,  \right)^{1/3} $$
$$ \left( 10 + \sqrt{-7}\, \right)^{1/3} $$
$$ \left( 10 + \sqrt{+7}\, \right)^{1/3} $$
\end{document}
```

The following image shows the output of `latex`. I obtain similar results with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`. Notice that `\sqrt{+7}` behaves as `\sqrt{-7}`, but different from `\sqrt{7}`.

[image: second example]

Comment: Please, could you compose a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that we see what exact font setup you have? And which compiler do you use -- `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: @yo' done. Also added an expression with more terms showing the same behavior.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can see that in the case of `\sqrt{-1}` the radical sign is a bit lower; if you do `\sqrt{\smash{-}1}`, the result will be the same.

This happens because the `-` character has a depth (equal to that of `+`).

On the other hand, you shouldn't use `\left` and `\right` in those cases. Note `\,` to space a bit the closing parenthesis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\text{wrong} &\quad&\left(\sqrt{1}\right)\left(\sqrt{-1}\right)\left(\sqrt{\smash{-}1}\right)
\\
&\text{right} &\quad&(\sqrt{1}\,)(\sqrt{\smash{-}1}\,)
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

More details. The character `+` extends below the baseline, so Knuth decided that `-` (in math mode, the minus sign) should share the same dimensions as `+`. This is true for the Computer Modern fonts, and may not be the case with other fonts.

This way, the two formulas `$a+b$` and `$a-b$` have the same height and depth, but `1` and `-1` don't: the latter has nonzero depth.

The radical sign is placed so it is vertically balanced with respect to the subformula it has to cover and, indeed, it is higher in `\sqrt{1}` than in `\sqrt{-1}`. This difference is sufficient for triggering a bigger size of the parentheses in the former case.

[image]

Comment: And `\sqrt{\vphantom{-}1` should then give the smaller parentheses, right?

Comment: "in *those* cases"? Didn't you want to write "in *any* cases"? ;-)

Comment: So I guess the `\sqrt{-1}` is complex. :)

Comment: @yo' But then `\left` and `\right` are useless (which they actually are here anyway).

Comment: @egreg I know, it was more a _what if_ question :-)

Comment: I do not know what "depth" is, but this looks like a bug.

Comment: @Alexey No, it's a precise choice: Knuth wanted a formula's height and depth not dependent on the presence of `+` and `-`: either of them produces the same height and depth. We could argue *ad infinitum* about the radical sign placement algorithm, though.

Comment: Here the height depends on the presence of `-`.

Comment: @Alexey Where's the `+`?

Comment: I said nothing about `+`. But here it is: `\sqrt{+-1}`.

Comment: @Alexey I was thinking to formulas such as `$a+r$` and `$a-r$`; they will have the same height and depth.

Comment: @egreg I know a `\left` and `\right` are useless in such basic expression, but it serves to show what I meant.  I edited my question to show another example.  But I expect that `\sqrt{}` will consider the total height of its argument to draw the sqrt symbol. Then, does the number `-1` have a smaller `\depth` or `\totalheight` than `1`?

Comment: @Alexey See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40985/27579) to see what `depth` is.