# CJK Character "一" is not vertically centered

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, cjk

I'm using XeLaTeX and Tikz for creating Kanji training sheets, but somehow it seems like the character 一 is not centered vertically, and hits too high. <s>First, I thought it was a font issue, but it seems centered in every other context (I've tested writing in Gimp and Chromium)</s>. Also, it happens for every CJK font. I'm using two fonts at the same time, but I believe you'd get the same result using any CJK font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans Mono CJK JP}
\newCJKfontfamily\drawingKanji{Chihaya Jyun}

\newcommand{\kanjiRow}[1]{
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\drawingKanji, text centered]

      % Main Frame
      \draw[line width=1.6pt, rounded corners=4pt] (0, 0) rectangle (14, 6);

      % Horizontal lines
      \draw (0,2) -- (14,2);
      \draw (0,4) -- (14,4);

      % Vertical lines
      \draw (2,0) -- (2,6);
      \draw (4,0) -- (4,6);
      \draw (6,0) -- (6,6);
      \draw (8,0) -- (8,6);
      \draw (10,0) -- (10,6);
      \draw (12,0) -- (12,6);

      % Grid Top
      \draw[dashed, opacity=.5] (0,5) -- (14,5);
      \draw[dashed, opacity=.5] (1,4) -- (1,6);
      \draw[dashed, opacity=.5] (3,4) -- (3,6);
      \draw[dashed, opacity=.5] (5,4) -- (5,6);
      \draw[dashed, opacity=.5] (7,4) -- (7,6);
      \draw[dashed, opacity=.5] (9,4) -- (9,6);
      \draw[dashed, opacity=.5] (11,4) -- (11,6);
      \draw[dashed, opacity=.5] (13,4) -- (13,6);

      % Grid Bottom
      \draw(0,1) -- (14,1);
      \draw (1,0) -- (1,2);
      \draw (3,0) -- (3,2);
      \draw (5,0) -- (5,2);
      \draw (7,0) -- (7,2);
      \draw (9,0) -- (9,2);
      \draw (11,0) -- (11,2);
      \draw (13,0) -- (13,2);

      % Big Characters 
      \draw (1,5) node[scale=5, font=\CJKfamily{Noto Sans CJK JP}]{#1};
      \draw (3,5) node[scale=5, opacity=.2, inner sep=0pt]{#1};
      \draw (5,5) node[scale=5, opacity=.15]{#1};
      \draw (7,5) node[scale=5, opacity=.12]{#1};
      \draw (9,5) node[scale=5, opacity=.08]{#1};
      \draw (11,5) node[scale=5, opacity=.04]{#1};

      % Small characters
      \draw (0.5,1.5) node[scale=2, font=\CJKfamily{Noto Sans CJK JP}]{#1};
      \draw (0.5,0.5) node[scale=2, opacity=.2]{#1};
      \draw (1.5,1.5) node[scale=2, opacity=.15]{#1};
      \draw (1.5,0.5) node[scale=2, opacity=.12]{#1};
      \draw (2.5,1.5) node[scale=2, opacity=.08]{#1};
      \draw (2.5,0.5) node[scale=2, opacity=.04]{#1};

    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \kanjiRow{時}
  \kanjiRow{一}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Edit: I found that I could narrow it down to being a font issue (contrary to what I thought previously) by encapsulating both characters by fboxes:

```
\fbox{\fbox{一}\fbox{時}}
```

which produces

[image]

And connects the question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40977/confused-with-tex-terminology-height-depth-width)

However, I'm still unsure about how center it.

Comment: Your code is not complete so I cannot test. But can you put `時` and `一` side by side to see if `一` is offset?

Comment: @Symbol1: I've edited the question and the code. It should be reproducable now. As you can see, it centers itself next to 時 even though the glyphs don't have the same height values.

Comment: OK. So the problem is definitely due to that `一` is not a square. Instead of `text centered`, you should use `anchor=base`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem!