# Representation of skillpoints on LaTeX

Tags: overleaf, cv

I would like to insert a section in my curriculum vitae where my skills are graphically represented(I'm using this template -> it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk). Since the spaces are limited I would like to delete the image that precedes the description of the skill (which in this case is the blue arrow). How could I do ?

```
% uniform icon style for all skill icons, e.g. flags or fontawesome icons
    \newcommand{\cvicon}[1]{\makebox[1em]{\color{iconcolor} #1}}


% \pointskill[<indent>]{<description>}{<points>}[<maxpoints>] creates
% | [indent] description  \hfill  ● ● ● ○ ○ |
% -- inspired by arravc.cls by LianTze Lim: https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV
\NewDocumentCommand{\pointskill}{ O{0em} m m m O{5} }{%
    \hspace{#1} \cvicon{#2} ~ #3 \hfill%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#5}{%
        \space%
        {\ifnumgreater{\x}{#4}{\color{skillbg}}{\color{iconcolor}}% from etoolbox
        % don't use totalheight; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41014
        \raisebox{0.5\height-0.4ex}{\scriptsize\faCircle}%
        }
    }\par%
}
```

graphic example of how it looks if I call \pointskill{►}{Python}{3} :
[image]

Comment: You probably just need to remove the `cvicon{#2}` and adjust the command in consequence, by writing `0{4}` and writing #2, #3 and #4 instead of #3, #4, #5. I post this as a comment because I have not tested it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the definition of `\pointskill` to ignore whatever is supplied as the second argument (noting that the first is optional):

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\pointskill}{ O{0em} m m m O{5} }{%
    \hspace{#1}#3 \hfill%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#5}{%
        \space%
        {\ifnumgreater{\x}{#4}{\color{skillbg}}{\color{iconcolor}}% from etoolbox
        % don't use totalheight; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41014
        \raisebox{0.5\height-0.4ex}{\scriptsize\faCircle}%
        }
    }\par%
}
```

You'll see there's no use of `#2` in the above definition, so you can still call it using

```
\pointskill{►}{Python}{3}
```

If you which to fully remove the option of passing a preceding icon, then use

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\pointskill}{ O{0em} m m O{5} }{%
    \hspace{#1}#2 \hfill%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#4}{%
        \space%
        {\ifnumgreater{\x}{#3}{\color{skillbg}}{\color{iconcolor}}% from etoolbox
        % don't use totalheight; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41014
        \raisebox{0.5\height-0.4ex}{\scriptsize\faCircle}%
        }
    }\par%
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is a really good solution! Unfortunately, I realized that even eliminating the image that precedes the description, the space occupied remains the same since the description shifts to the left. I believed that all the content shifted to the left in order to gain space.