How to strip off pt in generated file of coordinates?
The following code is used to create a box where a student can write answers, and to save the location of that box to an answers file:
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\strippt}[1]{%
  \StrBefore{#1}{pt}[\StrippedValue]%
  \StrippedValue%
}
%
% Create a box w x h where the user is expected to write an answer
% No correct answer is defined, just collect whatever is written
% the default size is w=72 x 36
\NewDocumentCommand{\ansbox}{O{72} O{36}}{%
  \pdfsavepos%
  \def\x{\the\dimexpr\pdfhorigin+\oddsidemargin\relax}%
  \def\y{\the\dimexpr\pdfvorigin+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep\relax}%
  \def\w{#1}%
  \def\h{#2}%
  \fbox{\makebox(\w pt,\h pt){}}%
  \immediate\write\ansfile{\number\value{questioncount}_\number\value{anscount} %
    \strippt{\the\numexpr\x/65536\relax}\space%
    \strippt{\the\numexpr\y/65536\relax}\space%
    \w\space \h\space f \space}%
  \stepcounter{anscount}%
}

Without \strippt, it works, but there are pt units in the file
0_0 36.135pt/65536\relax  36.135pt/65536\relax  162 36 f
0_1 36.135pt/65536\relax  36.135pt/65536\relax  50 36 f
0_2 36.135pt/65536\relax  36.135pt/65536\relax  50 36 f
1_0 0.00055pt 0.00055pt 72 36 f 5
strippt is obviously wrong. I just don't understand how to debug this sort of thing.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Doing \pdfsavepos is useless unless you use \pdflastxpos or \pdflastypos. And \immediate\write is obviously wrong, as the position is only known when the page is shipped out. Anyway your \strippt cannot work in \write, because it doesn't work by macro expansion only..

\the\numexpr\x/65536\relax}  numexpr will produce a number so an integer with no units, so there is nothing for \strippt to do even if it could work in that location.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591720/equivalent-of-pdfsavepos-for-a-box  is a good example on using \pdfsavebox.
