# How to draw half colored icon in point skills' CV template

Tags: xetex, cv, icon

I would like to have in my CV semi-filled circles instead of only full ones (like now in the picture), but I can't manage to change the code. Can someone please help me out?

The part to modify is as follow:

```
% \pointskill[<indent>]{<icon>}{<description>}{<points>}[<maxpoints>] creates
% | [indent] [icon]  description  \hfill  ● ● ● ○ ○ |
% -- inspired by arravc.cls by LianTze Lim: https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV
\NewDocumentCommand{\pointskill}{ O{0em} m m m O{5} }{%
    \hspace{#1} \cvicon{#2} ~ #3 \hfill%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#5}{%
        \space%
        {\ifnumgreater{\x}{#4}{\color{skillbg}}{\color{iconcolor}}% from etoolbox
        % don't use totalheight; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41014
        \raisebox{0.5\height-0.4ex}{\scriptsize\faCircle}%
        }
    }\par%
}
```

and in the text to produce the image is

```
\profilesection{Languages}
        \pointskill{\flag{IT.png}}{Italien}{5}
        \pointskill{\flag{EN.png}}{Anglais}{4}
        \pointskill{\flag{FR.png}}{French}{4}
```

[image]

The template I'm using is at this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk).

Thanks, Cecilia

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. External links are discouraged because your question might become meaningless if/when the link disappears (next week, or next year, or... ).

Comment: In Font Awsome look for and try https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle-half?s=duotone&f=classic : fa-duotone and fa-circle-half . Don't know if it's provided by Latex. // Unfortunately it's not, see https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf . But why not replacing the circles by star-half-full / \faStarHalfFull  , see page 14 ? // And if all fails, you still can replace the fa- by some tiny tikz-pic's .