# Measuring TikZ leaves and using measurements to set sibling distance?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, dimensions

## TL;DR Summary:

Is there some way to measure the width of a leaf node and pass this measurement back up the tree to be used in setting `sibling distance`?  (One might want to do a similar thing for `level distance` as well.)

## Example:

Suppose that I have a simple tree where the leaf nodes each contain the same image:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclareimage{image}{fptp-ballot}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {root} [level/.append style={level distance=4cm}]
      child foreach \c in {1,2} {
        node [fill=red!10] {\pgfuseimage{image}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the default setting for `sibling distance`, the leaves overlap:

[image]

One way that we could measure the width of the leaf is to create an invisible temporary leaf, `tmp`, and use the `let` operation for paths to compute its width:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfdeclareimage{image}{fptp-ballot}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (tmp) [fill=red!10, transparent, overlay] {\pgfuseimage{image}};

    \path let \p{leafwidth} = ($(tmp.east)-(tmp.west)$) in
     node {root} [level/.append style={level distance=4cm, sibling distance=\x{leafwidth}}]
      child foreach \c in {1,2} {
        node [fill=red!10] {\pgfuseimage{image}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem with this approach is:  It seems clumsy to need to create a temporary leaf, `tmp`, when the leaves that I really want to measure already exist later in the code.  This makes things less modular.  If I change the leaves, then I need to change the `tmp` node correspondingly (or factor out the leaf code with a macro and style).

In other words, I'd like a solution that works *locally* regardless of what I put inside the leaves -- a single image, a matrix with arbitrary cell content, etc.

## Question:

Is there some way to directly measure the width of an *actual* leaf node and pass this measurement back up the tree to be used in setting `sibling distance`?

I would like to write something like the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {root} [level/.append style={level distance=4cm, sibling distance=\x{leaf1width}}]
    child foreach \c in {1,2} {
      node (leaf\c)
         [fill=red!10] {\pgfuseimage{image}}
      let \p{leaf\c width} = ($(leaf\c.east)-(leaf\c.west)$) in};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here I am directly measuring the widths of the *actual* leaves and am trying to use this to set `sibling distance` at the root node.  Unfortunately, this gives the error "Undefined control sequence.  `<argument> \x{leaf1width}`", presumably because `\p{leaf\c width}` is not defined until the leaves are reached.  Is there any way to fix this code?

I thought about using the `late options` key, but the [TikZ manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) states that

> An already existing node is determined [...] and, then, the options are executed in a local scope. Most of these options will have no effect since you *cannot change the appearance of the node*, that is, you cannot change a red node into a green node using late options.

Indeed, the following compiles without error, but the `sibling distance` is not affected.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (root) {root} [level/.append style={level distance=4cm}]
    child foreach \c in {1,2} {
      node (leaf\c)
           [fill=red!10] {\pgfuseimage{image}}
      let \p{leaf\c width} = ($(leaf\c.east)-(leaf\c.west)$) in
      (root) [late options={level/.append style={sibling distance=\x{leaf1width}}}]};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I always use Yiannis' answer to get the size of the image: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3664/3235 You can first pass it through that solution get the relevant lengths and then start the TikZ part.

Answer (score 3):

As linked in the comments, putting your images to a box first makes it very easy to measure the size of the image. I am not sure that I understand the complication but if you have few images that would go into the tree then you can take the maximum of those measurements via `max(x,y)` from math library. Here I've stripped down the macros and used Yiannis' solution without any automation.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\Image}
\savebox{\Image}{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{DSOTM}}
\newlength{\imageh}
\newlength{\imagew}
\settoheight{\imageh}{\usebox{\Image}}
\settowidth{\imagew}{\usebox{\Image}}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {root}  [level/.append style={
                      level distance=1.5\imageh, sibling distance=1.1\imagew
                      }
                  ]
      child foreach \c in {1,2} {
        node [fill=red!10,inner sep=1pt] {\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{DSOTM}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Yiannis's image measurement macros; I hadn't seen it before and it will be useful.  Unfortunately, though, it doesn't quite solve my problem, since I'd like the solution to work regardless of what I put inside the leaves -- a single image, a matrix with arbitrary cell content, etc.  Also, I am hoping that the solution will local to the actual leaf, so that if I change the leaf contents, I don't need to remember to change something elsewhere (e.g. the saved box).  I've edited my question to (hopefully) clarify.

Comment: Can you make this tree in _Any Colour You Like_?

Comment: @TomBombadil :) with enough *Brain Damage*, *Time*, and, *Money* anything is possible!

Comment: @HenryDeYoung Isee. I'll try to think something else

Comment: @percusse Maybe it's not possible to measure the _actual_ leaves and feed it back... Maybe the best thing is to factor out the leaf contents into a macro.  I just thought it was worth asking if anyone had an idea.  Thanks.

Comment: It's possible but you get a chicken egg problem. For example, you can a little crazy and prepare your nodes with `\pgfpositionnodelater` and other stuff before you start your tree. But I don't know how to make it Henry De Young-friendly yet such that complicated stuff happens in the preamble :)