# How can I determine the height of a minipage?

Tags: minipage, dimensions, height

If I have a `minipage`

```
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
content
\end{minipage}
```

How can I determine its height and save this value as a length?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/get-the-size-that-a-figure-is-being-rendered

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\newlength\foo

\settoheight\foo{\begin{minipage.....
```

If you also want to typeset the minipage you may want to save it in a box and instead say

```
\settoheight\foo{\usebox\mybox}
```

rather than typesetting it twice once just for measuring purposes.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. However, if I use a complicated content in the minipage (a large tikz image), I get a `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]` error.

Comment: Yes, both versions fail due to the same error but the standalone minipage works. I use this code in a `\newcommand` environment, so I have something like `\newsavebox{\sb}\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{  \savebox{\b}{...minipage{#1}...}\settoheight{\foo}{\usebox{\sb}}\print{\usebox{\sb}}  }`.

Comment: the newcommand there will add one extra input stack entry so you could try it without that. On the version that works what is the line in the log (about 8 lines from the end) file that looks like `63i,9n,74p,723b,1727s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s`   in particular what is the first number before `i` I suspect that you only _just_ made it:-)

Comment: `5000i,10n,75p,552b,1292s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s`. Please excuse me blowing up this rather simple question, but there seems to be a problem with the whole `\savebox` formalism when I use it in a tikz node. Probably my problem is related to that.

Comment: your tikz code used up the entire save stack 5000 out of 5000 that means you are living on borrowed time, one more newcommand or input or a passing butterfly and your document will fail. Possibly you should ask a tikz specific question with an example and ask why it has eaten so much save stack.

Comment: It seems that, if there are multiple lines in the minipage, it is important to include the `[b]` option. Otherwise, the height comes out wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We can also directly use `savebox`. Note that if you're using this in a command you need to define the box outside of the command. MWE to follow:

```latex
\newbox\hintbox
\newcommand*{\cvcomment}[2][.25em]{
    \sbox\hintbox{
        \begin{minipage}{\hintscolumnwidth - \separatorcolumnwidth}
            \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2}
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \usebox\hintbox
    \vspace{-1.7\ht\hintbox}
}
```

For context, I use this in `modern-cv` to leave a comment in the left column (the dates column), and that's where `\hintscolumnwidth`, `\hintstyle`, etc. come from.

In the above, I've defined the box `hintbox` outside of the command. I typeset a minipage inside `hintbox`, and display it using `usebox`. The whole point is that since I have it in a box, I can now measure its height `\ht\hintbox` and scale it appropriately to bring up content that comes after the use of the command such that the box doesn't take vertical space.