# Curve CV - Photo in Rubric

Tags: graphics, positioning

I just started to create my CV by using `CurVe` package ([CurVe at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/curve)). But while I tried to include my photo inside the personal category I had some troubles, because I was not able to place the image properly.

Can someone tell me how to place the image inside a rubrics element properly?

At the moment the rubric looks like this:

```
\begin{rubric}{Persönliches} % Titel der Rubrikb
\noentry{03/2013 --- 04/2014} 

\entry*[Name] Stefan MyName

\entry*[Geburtsdatum und -ort] 11.11.1111 in Ducktown

\entry*[Staatsangehörigkeit] deutsch

\end{rubric}
```

and the main document like this

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,12pt,german]{curve}
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} % fuer Macuser
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% die Raender je nach Bedarf anpassen
\usepackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}


\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % die Sprachen einstellen, die Du benoetigst
\usepackage{textcomp} % Paket um Trademarks etc. kennzeichnen zu koennen
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Paket zur Positionierung einbinden
\usepackage{graphicx} % Paket zur Verwendung von .jpg Bildern


\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}


\usepackage{color} % farbige Links
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % klickbare Links im PDF

% Um keinen Einzug bei Subrubriken zu erzeugen
%\makeatletter
%\def\@@subrubric#1{\rule{0bp}{\@beforespace}{\@subrubricfont#1}
%\@subrubricmark{#1}}
%% Um eine waagerechte Linie vor Überschriften einzufügen
%\def\hrulefill{\color{Gray}\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1pt\hfill\kern\z@}
%\makeatother


%\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.5}  % dunkelblaue Links
%\hypersetup{pdftex=true, colorlinks=true, breaklinks=true,%
 %linkcolor=darkblue, menucolor=darkblue, urlcolor=darkblue}
 %


 % rubric topic sizes
\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries}


\flavor{detail}

% Wer bist Du? z. B. Assistant Professor, Chief Engineer, Senior Executive:
%\title{Lebenslauf}
%\title{Stefan ssss}
\title{Lebenslauf}

% Beschreibe Dich genauer, z.B.
\subtitle{Stefan ssss, B.Sc.}


% Abstand zwischen dem Titel einer Subrubrik und der folgenden Aufzaehlung
\setlength\subrubricspace{3ex}

% Anpassung/Einstellung fuer Aufzaehlungszeichen vor den Taetigkeitsbeschreibungen:
% \usepackage{pifont} % nur falls man die Aufzaehlungszeichen braucht
% \prefix{\ding{43}} % setzt einen Zeigefinger als Listenpunkt vor den Eintrag

% falls eine Rubrik ueber die Seite hinausreicht, wird die Rubrikueberschrift
% auf der naechsten Seite wiederholt, gefolgt von einem Fortsetzungshinweis in Klammern:
\continuedname{~~(...)} % Englisch




\leftheader{str. 47 \\ 1111 somewhere}
\rightheader{+49 176 333 33333327 \Mobilefone \linebreak 3333@gmail.com \Email}


\begin{document}

\makeheaders
\maketitle


\prefix{}
\makerubric{personal}
\prefix{-}
\makerubric{experience}
\prefix{-}
\makerubric{education} 
\prefix{-}
\makerubric{ausland} 
\prefix{-}
\makerubric{mitgliedschaften}
\prefix{}
\pagebreak
\makerubric{skills}
\prefix{-}
\makerubric{references}

\prefix{}
\makerubric{publications}

\pagebreak
\prefix{-}
\makerubric{projects}
\prefix{}
\makerubric{skilllist}

\vspace{3cm}

Stefan sss \\
ssss, den \today 

\end{document} % schliesst das Hauptdokument
```

[image: image position]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: thx. just added my main file

Answer (score 2):

The following code gives the result that you want, although it may not do it "properly": The `rubric` environment is not changed at all, but the image is inserted manually.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,12pt,german]{curve}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp-filecontents-personal.tex}
\begin{rubric}{Persönliches}
\noentry{03/2013 --- 04/2014} 

\entry*[Name] Stefan MyName

\entry*[Geburtsdatum und -ort] 11.11.1111 in Ducktown

\entry*[Staatsangehörigkeit] deutsch

\end{rubric}
\end{filecontents}

\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\subtitle{Stefan ssss, B.Sc.}
\setlength\subrubricspace{3ex}

\leftheader{str. 47 \\ 1111 somewhere}
\rightheader{+xxx xx xxxxxxx \Mobilefone \linebreak nobody@localhost \Email}

\begin{document}
\def\mygraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\newlength\graphicheight
\setlength\graphicheight{\heightof{\mygraphic}}

\makeheaders
\maketitle

\prefix{}
\hfill
\mygraphic
\vspace{-\graphicheight}
\makerubric{tmp-filecontents-personal}
\vspace{3cm}

Stefan sss \\
ssss, den \today 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The procedure explained:

1. A `\hfill` leaves space on the left side of the page
2. The (manually sized) image is inserted
3. A negative vertical space matching the height of the image is inserted to go back to the previous vertical position.
4. `\makerubric` is called and appears to work as if there was no picture

I borrowed code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3658/23160) by Will Robertson for determining the size of the image.

Comment: wuhu! thank you so much! :-) (i expected that so a dirty hack is necessary ;()