# Generating TikZ Nodes and Labels from Custom Array Strings

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am trying to use the TikZ environment to annotate a graphic with labels in multiple specific locations. Instead of repeating the node command many times and changing the node location and label, I would really like for TikZ to use coordinates and labels from custom strings that I input, along with the `\foreach` command.

Also, these coordinates should be given as dimensionless decimal scalars (0-1) of the total graphic width and height, so that the nodes are in respective locations even if total width/height changes. I get the scaled figure's height from specified width thanks to Will Robertson's answer to a question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/get-the-size-that-a-figure-is-being-rendered).

I have a non-functioning MWE here which should take this first image and add labels like in the second. Perhaps someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\usepackage{calc}

\def\site{{1,2,3,4,5}} %Load labels
\def\xdim{{0.038,0.149,0.488,0.668,0.872
}} %Load dimensionless x-coordinates for labels
\def\ydim{{0.57,0.908,0.713,0.632,0.688
}} %Load dimensionless y-coordinates for labels

\begin{document}
    \newlength\gw
    \setlength\gw{10cm} %Load graphic width
    \def\mygraphic{\includegraphics[width=\gw]{label_this.jpg}}
    \newlength\gh
    \setlength\gh{\heightof{\mygraphic}} %Graphic height
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\gw]{label_this.jpg}};
            \foreach \i in {0,...,4}
            {
            \node at (\xdim[\i]\gw,\ydim[\i]\gh) {\site[\i]};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Labelled Graphic}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can access list items with `[number]` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. You forgot multiplication signs, forgot to parse the node content, and do not need the `calc` package, the library of the same name allows you to do the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\site{{1,2,3,4,5}} %Load labels
\def\xdim{{0.038,0.149,0.488,0.668,0.872
}} %Load dimensionless x-coordinates for labels
\def\ydim{{0.57,0.908,0.713,0.632,0.688
}} %Load dimensionless y-coordinates for labels

\begin{document}
    \newlength\gw
    \setlength\gw{10cm} %Load graphic width
    \def\mygraphic{\includegraphics[width=\gw]{label_this.jpg}}
%     \newlength\gh
%     \setlength\gh{\heightof{\mygraphic}} %Graphic height
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[inner sep=0pt] (grph) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\gw]{label_this.jpg}};
            \path let \p1=($(grph.north)-(grph.south)$) in
            \pgfextra{\xdef\gh{\y1}};
            \foreach \i in {0,...,4}
            {
            \node at (\xdim[\i]*\gw-4.5cm,\ydim[\i]*\gh-2.5cm) {\pgfmathparse{\site[\i]}%
            \pgfmathresult};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Labelled Graphic}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! The only thing I then did differently from this was instead of subtracting manually half the box size (about 4.5cm by 2.5cm): 
`\node at (\xdim[\i]*\gw-4.5cm,\ydim[\i]*\gh-2.5cm)...`
I subtracted half of the graphic size in both directions:
 `\node at (\xdim[\i]*\gw-0.5*\gw,\ydim[\i]*\gh-0.5*\gh)...`

To preserve the scalability that I mentioned. Thank you!